# Duplicate Entry Mysql Primary

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

Got some error within this code, 
have tried to debug but couldn't find the answer.

Does anyone can correct me please?

```
BEGIN

DECLARE FINALID VARCHAR(8);
DECLARE MAXIDCOMPANY VARCHAR(8);

        SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(company.idCompany,3,8))+1 INTO MAXIDCOMPANY 
        FROM company 
        WHERE SUBSTRING(company.idCompany,1,2) = SUBSTRING(nmCompany,1,2);


                IF MAXIDCOMPANY > 0 AND MAXIDCOMPANY < 10 THEN
                    SET FINALID = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(nmCompany,1,2),'00', CONVERT(MAXIDCOMPANY USING latin1));
                    ELSEIF MAXIDCOMPANY > 9 AND MAXIDCOMPANY < 100 THEN
                        SET FINALID = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(nmCompany,1,2),'0', CONVERT(MAXIDCOMPANY USING latin1));
                            ELSEIF MAXIDCOMPANY > 99  THEN
                            SET FINALID = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(nmCompany,1,2), CONVERT(MAXIDCOMPANY USING latin1));
                END IF;

                        IF MAXIDCOMPANY IS NULL THEN
                            SET FINALID = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(nmCompany,1,2),'001');
                        END IF;

                INSERT INTO company
                (company.idCompany, company.nmCompany, company.country, company.address, company.region, company.joinDate, company.quota, company.createdUser, company.createdDate, company.updatedUser, company.updatedDate)
                VALUES
                (FINALID, nmCompany, country, address, region, joinDate, quota, createdUser, NOW(), updatedUser, updatedDate);



END
```

That's the code, the program stuck to counter after next to 1000.

EXAMPLE :

When I add the data for example IN1000 as the idCompany, it always stucks on that number, but when I query the maximum data it shows IN999 only, why not the IN1000

Huge thanks

Comment: Well... it is not easy to answer not knowing shat the code _should_ do, how it _failed_, what are your _table structures_ and without having a sample of input data...

Answer (score 0):

Because the function max combine with SUB-STRING will return the maximum value within variable character, and the solution for this is substitute it with count function  and the logic count will return the maximum value.

```
SELECT COUNT(company.idCompany) + 1 INTO MAXIDCOMPANY from company where SUBSTRING(company.idCompany,1,2) = SUBSTRING(company.idCompany,1,2);
```

based on my business proses, thank you all for the answer..